# Замена элемента в ListBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

есть ListBox, в который добавляются: Имя, Фамилия, Почта. Нужно по нажатию на элемент ListBox'a заменить его значение.
PS
При нажатии на кнопку "Добавить" появляется новое окно с тремя компонентами TextBox, в которые вводятся данные, при нажатии на кнопку "Применить" введенные данные добавляются в ListBox
Код User.cs

```
public class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Код MAINFORM.cs

```
 public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void usersList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string userData = (string)usersList.SelectedItem;
        string[] userDataArray = userData.Split(' ');

        if (userDataArray.Length != 3)
            throw new Exception("Данные повреждены");

        User user = new User
        {
            FirstName = userDataArray[0],
            LastName = userDataArray[1],
            Email = userDataArray[2]
        };
        UserDataEditor window = new UserDataEditor(user);
        window.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserDataEditor window = new UserDataEditor();
        window.ShowDialog();
        User newUser = window.User;
        if (newUser != null)
            usersList.Items.Add($"{newUser.FirstName}" +
                $" {newUser.LastName} {newUser.Email}");
    }
}
```

Код UserDateEditor.cs

```
 public partial class UserDataEditor : Form
{
    public User User { get; private set; } = null;
    public UserDataEditor(User user = null)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (user != null)
        {
            User = user;

            userFirstNameEditor.Text = User.FirstName;
            userLastNameEditor.Text = User.LastName;
            userEmailEditor.Text = User.Email;
        }
    }

    private void AcceptButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        User = new User
        {
            FirstName = userFirstNameEditor.Text,
            LastName = userLastNameEditor.Text,
            Email = userEmailEditor.Text
        };
        this.Close();
    }
```

[image: MainForm]

[image: UserDateEditor]

Answer (score 0):

ответ на первый вопрос (по нажатию на элемент ListBox'a заменить его значение)

```
 UserDataEditor window = new UserDataEditor(user);
 window.ShowDialog();
```

не хватает обработки

```
User updatedUser = window.User;
...
```

во втором при нажатии на кнопку "Применить"
если делаете ShowDialog(), то пользуйтесь DialogResult для понимания события от закрытия формы.

Смотрите на примеры [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult?view=netcore-3.1) и [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: Не понял. Объясните пожалуйста

Comment: ВЫ активируете форму через ShowDialog, тогда и использовать надо DialogResult понять как форма была закрыта. Результат конечно нужно брать из полей формы и добавлять в лист. Посмотрите на usersList_SelectedIndexChanged вы не обрабатываете ответ совсем.

Comment: int i = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
    listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i);
    listBox1.Items.Insert(i, textBox1.Text);

Я делал так, при изменении исключение вылетает

Comment: Я не понял как использовать DialogResult, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Диалоговая форма. когда вы закрываете её то перед закрытием посмотрите на свойство DialogResult

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста, я не могу разобраться с этой ошибкой https://codeshare.io/Gk8BJA

Comment: int i = listBox1.SelectedIndex; listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i); listBox1.Items.Insert(i, textBox1.Text);  измените поля listBox1.Items[SelectedIndex] либо listBox1.Items[SelectedIndex] = updatedUser

Comment: Что с кодом в ссылке?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108880/discussion-between-student-and-aziz-umarov).